# What should I do if I managed to solve my own problem without a logic solution?

Tags: discussion

Yesteday, I've posted [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121719/cant-see-wep-networks-with-airodump-ng) about a problem I had with finding WEP networks in `airodump-ng`.

Today, surprisingly, I've been able to find my WEP network, without noticeable reason.

What should I do with my original question? Should I answer it without any informative details? Should I just delete it?

Comment: Just my 2 cents: Problems that go away for no reason, come back for no reason too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know why (i.e. you have a solution) then post an answer with details.

If the question and any potential answer does not add to the community or no one else could benefit from your experience, I'd consider deleting the question.